# JMeter 5.4.3 I like to see only transactions NOT all samples

Tags: jmeter

I like to see only combined transaction. Not all samples. I check Transaction Controller "Generate parent sample"
But still I get all samples in results.

Please help and let me know how can I stop seeing all child samples.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add the next line to *user.properties* file:

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.subresults=false
```

JMeter restart will be required to pick the property up, once done you will "stop seeing all child samples"

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Results file configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I did add the line you suggested. Restarted JMeter 5.4.3 and the problem is still same.  It did not fix the issue. 
In non guil test HTML Result still showing all samples in result.

I will highly appreciate some more solutions and suggessions. 

Thanks